# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Other articles on here haven't been able to solve my issue. The following errors are being thrown when I run my ASP.NET MVC5 Web Project.

Anyone got an idea where I am going wrong?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)



=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/{name}/Documents/git/Project/
 LOG: Initial PrivatePath =         C:\Users\{name}\Documents\git\Project\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown)
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\{name}\Documents\git\Project\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\{name}\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference:     Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/{name}/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/b2d7334d/e3876cf7/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/{name}/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET     Files/vs/b2d7334d/e3876cf7/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/{name}/Documents/git/Project/bin/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Have you install the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nuget package?

Comment: I have not done that manually. I have been working on this project for the past few months (for school) and only now it returns this error). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you check if you have Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll in your bin, and what's the version?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We just had this error in one of our test environments.  The problem was in the web.config file.  The  section had settings to reference the DotNetCompilerPlatform assembly, but had the wrong version number.  We updated web.config to the proper version number and it fixed the error.

```
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

Comment: After I installed the Nuget package, it did update the Web.config, but not the one nested under it (web.base.config), so when I built the project, it got overwritten. To fix this, when you install the Nuget package, copy the changed part of the parent Web.config file, then replace the corresponding section in your nested config file.

Answer (score 22):

This problem comes from your Nuget package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`.

It is the wrong version. You can remove the Current Version then install again from Nuget.

Answer (score 6):

Just run this command in the Package Manager Console:

> Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r

Answer (score 4):

It can also happen if your target folder is something other than "bin/".   Roslyn by default looks for the "roslyn" folder in the "bin" folder, so if you are compiling, for example, to "bin/debug/", there may not be a roslyn folder there, and thus it can't find the provider.

You can fix this by reverting to a plain "bin/" target, or by ensuring that a full roslyn folder is copied across to the "bin/debug/" folder as a Post-Build event.   Because a publish always pushes to the correct target folder despite the compilation target folder of your build machine, that's why it fails when you run locally, but works if you deploy it.

(Some people have the opposite problem, it working locally, but fails when deployed to IIS, because IIS doesn't have a copy of the CodeDom provider in its GAC, but that's a totally different issue.)

Answer (score 2):

You may get this error if

1. You published a different version (e.g., a different GIT branch) of your application than previously and
2. You recently made a major migration to a different .NET or C# compiler version.

If this is the case, then the problem may be resolved by deleting the target folder you are publishing to and then publishing your application again.

A possible explanation WHY this happens may be in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609105/2279059

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.  Panic averted.  I did make a major migration and everything was working and testing fine until I uploaded it to my hosting provider, then it crashed.  I normally don't delete everything, because if you don't there's no downtime, but in this case it worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022, Updating Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform is solution for me.

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037305/5337709

My Web.config looks like before "Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" as:

```
<compilers>
   <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
   <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

After update;

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by according to the response of Jeff Woods :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Tools  --> NuGet Package Manager --> Installed
2. search as  Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

see the right side , if there any version different , update that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on visual studio 2019 where i cannot install / uninstall the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nugget.

it was solve by moving my project directory to root because the **accessing path was too long** D:\Projets\2023**************\transfert\20231028DEV_*****2022_2023\DEV******_2022_2023\ProcessAndWeb_VS********************\PROJetDirectory
=> move to a shorter path as:
D:\DEV_*****_2022_2023\ProcessAndWeb_VS********************\PROJetDirectory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).